# How to check for the latest version in an Azure Feed *Without a PAT*

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am deploying a Python application to an Azure feed. I want it to be able to check that feed again during runtime to see if a new version has been posted. I can do that via the API with a PAT, but that's too complicated for my users for a simple update check.

It's possible to check it in a browser with no extra logins (I assume it somehow auto-logins when you navigate there), so I assume that this is possible from a Python app too. Is it possible to do this without using Selenium?